# Angular Universal and jQuery (ignore $ on server)

Tags: jquery, angular-universal

My angular app uses jquery for various plugins that need it as a dependency and other client side tasks.

Problem is that universal cannot understand what to do because jquery manipulates dom elements which do not exist server side.

> ERROR ReferenceError: $ is not defined

The ultimate goal is just to ignore jquery tasks server side. Ive read solutions that suggests putting all dom manipulation in a client only service and another solutions that uses `if (isBrowser) { /* jQuery here */ }` ... But that is not ideal to wrap every dom situation.

https://medium.com/@zainzafar/localstorage-with-angular-universal-2a111fb4af72

Both of those are decent ideas but im looking for something more elegant. that will ignore jquery ($) without error-ing out. for example the following patch (put in `server.ts`) will not error out everytime `document` or `window` are used. No need to modify clients files just to ignore it server side.

```
const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const template = fs.readFileSync('./dist/browser/index.html').toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(template);
global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;
```

Before you tell me not to use jQuery. Trust me. I know. but that decision was out of my hands and that is not what im asking here.

#### edit

I ran into this article. He has found a simple solve to suppress localstorage errors and window errors... Im looking for a solution like this for jquery
https://blog.khophi.co/localstorage-undefined-angular-server-side-rendering/

Comment: Hey Omar, did you find the solution to this ? As I'm looking for an exact same solution